# main's char *argv[] doesn't include arguments if stdin is file

Tags: c, posix, stdin, io-redirection, argv

I'm a little newbie in C.

```
./main 7 4
```

This command in terminal causes that argv[1] = 7, argv[2] = 4.

```
./main <input.in
```

When I use redirecting of stdin in terminal, it only shows argc = 1(./main).

Is there any way how to solve this problem or do i have to try a different way?

Comment: `stdin` is not the same as the *command line arguments* passed to a program.

Comment: "*Is there any way how to solve this problem*" Which problem? You described a well defined behaviour, but did not tell us what the problem is.

Comment: For the 2nd example use any kind of *reading* from `stdin` (Standard Input) to get your numbers.

Comment: So i have to use scanf?

Comment: OK, but it's harder to do it with scanf.

Comment: If you instead do `./main input.in`, then `argv[1] = input.in`. You can then open that file using `fopen(argv[1], "r")` to read that file listed on the command line.

Comment: OK, but this is my hw to school and i have to read it from stdin

Comment: You might want to use fgets() plus sscanf() or similiar functions to get the values via stdin.   I can assure you that getting data from a file, through stdin is much easier (and more reliable) that inputing command line parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You shell interprets the `<file.txt` as "send file.txt's contents to this processes' stdin", so your program will never see the `<file.txt` part.

There is no way to resolve this, as this is a deliberate feature of POSIX (and possibly other) shells.

Answer (score 0):

We since you are on Ubuntu and using a terminal, I'll assume you are using bash. The problem you are experiencing is not a real c problem but how bash starts your program.

The terminal hooks in the prase `./program [args, ...] < redirected`, bash call internally the `exec` function to start your program and will setup the environment for your program. It sets up your program with any of the args between [] but after and including the "<" redirection symbols. It is not presented to your program as an argument but it hooks it up to the standard input.

So if you would like to do something  with it you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int mychar = getchar(stdin).
```

because the `FILE* stdin`; is already opened for it. The stdin file would otherwise accept input from the keyboard, but will now read from the file. You are ofcourse not limited to getchar you can take many c function from stdio.h that take a FILE* and use it.